# Promise not resolving in custom TypeAhead directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I edited the TypeAhead directive that is part of Angular UI for AngularJS so it will only give suggestions based on the most recent word, delimited by space (" ").

I intend to use it to for something like a query builder, dynamically giving suggestions based on surrounding syntax. This works as expected for the first word, but once we get to the second word, the promise does not resolve anymore for some reason. The value of inputValue is correct and as expected, but the code inside

`$q.when(parserResult.source(originalScope, locals)).then(function (matches) {`

does not appear to get run. Please advise.

My code (exactly the same as original except for I added a function called getLastWord that truncates the current expression :

```
angular.module('customTypeahead', ['ui.bootstrap.position', 'ui.bootstrap.bindHtml'])

.factory('customTypeaheadParser', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

    //                      00000111000000000000022200000000000000003333333333333330000000000044000
    var TYPEAHEAD_REGEXP = /^\s*([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+as\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w\d]*))\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)$/;

    return {
        parse: function (input) {

            var match = input.match(TYPEAHEAD_REGEXP);
            if (!match) {
                throw new Error(
                    'Expected customTypeahead specification in form of "_modelValue_ (as _label_)? for _item_ in _collection_"' +
                    ' but got "' + input + '".');
            }

            return {
                itemName: match[3],
                source: $parse(match[4]),
                viewMapper: $parse(match[2] || match[1]),
                modelMapper: $parse(match[1])
            };
        }
    };
}])

.directive('customTypeahead', ['$compile', '$parse', '$q', '$timeout', '$document', '$rootScope', '$position', 'customTypeaheadParser',
    function ($compile, $parse, $q, $timeout, $document, $rootScope, $position, customTypeaheadParser) {

        var HOT_KEYS = [9, 13, 27, 38, 40];

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (originalScope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

                //SUPPORTED ATTRIBUTES (OPTIONS)

                //minimal no of characters that needs to be entered before customTypeahead kicks-in
                var minLength = originalScope.$eval(attrs.customTypeaheadMinLength);
                if (!minLength && minLength !== 0) {
                    minLength = 0;
                }

                //minimal wait time after last character typed before customTypeahead kicks-in
                var waitTime = originalScope.$eval(attrs.customTypeaheadWaitMs) || 0;

                //should it restrict model values to the ones selected from the popup only?
                var isEditable = originalScope.$eval(attrs.customTypeaheadEditable) !== false;

                //binding to a variable that indicates if matches are being retrieved asynchronously
                var isLoadingSetter = $parse(attrs.customTypeaheadLoading).assign || angular.noop;

                //a callback executed when a match is selected
                var onSelectCallback = $parse(attrs.customTypeaheadOnSelect);

                var inputFormatter = attrs.customTypeaheadInputFormatter ? $parse(attrs.customTypeaheadInputFormatter) : undefined;

                var appendToBody = attrs.customTypeaheadAppendToBody ? originalScope.$eval(attrs.customTypeaheadAppendToBody) : false;

                var focusFirst = originalScope.$eval(attrs.customTypeaheadFocusFirst) !== false;

                //INTERNAL VARIABLES

                //model setter executed upon match selection
                var $setModelValue = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign;

                //expressions used by customTypeahead
                var parserResult = customTypeaheadParser.parse(attrs.customTypeahead);

                var hasFocus;

                //create a child scope for the customTypeahead directive so we are not polluting original scope
                //with customTypeahead-specific data (matches, query etc.)
                var scope = originalScope.$new();
                originalScope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    scope.$destroy();
                });

                // WAI-ARIA
                var popupId = 'customTypeahead-' + scope.$id + '-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
                element.attr({
                    'aria-autocomplete': 'list',
                    'aria-expanded': false,
                    'aria-owns': popupId
                });

                //pop-up element used to display matches
                var popUpEl = angular.element('<div custom-typeahead-popup></div>');
                popUpEl.attr({
                    id: popupId,
                    matches: 'matches',
                    active: 'activeIdx',
                    select: 'select(activeIdx)',
                    query: 'query',
                    position: 'position'
                });
                //custom item template
                if (angular.isDefined(attrs.customTypeaheadTemplateUrl)) {
                    popUpEl.attr('template-url', attrs.customTypeaheadTemplateUrl);
                }

                var resetMatches = function () {
                    scope.matches = [];
                    scope.activeIdx = -1;
                    element.attr('aria-expanded', false);
                };

                var getMatchId = function (index) {
                    return popupId + '-option-' + index;
                };

                // Indicate that the specified match is the active (pre-selected) item in the list owned by this customTypeahead.
                // This attribute is added or removed automatically when the `activeIdx` changes.
                scope.$watch('activeIdx', function (index) {
                    if (index < 0) {
                        element.removeAttr('aria-activedescendant');
                    } else {
                        element.attr('aria-activedescendant', getMatchId(index));
                    }
                });

                var getLastWord = function (expression) {
                    if (expression === "") {
                        return "";
                    }
                    var temp = expression.split(" ");
                    return temp[temp.length - 1];
                };

                var getMatchesAsync = function (inputValue) {
                    inputValue = getLastWord(inputValue);
                    var locals = {$viewValue: inputValue};
                    isLoadingSetter(originalScope, true);
                    $q.when(parserResult.source(originalScope, locals)).then(function (matches) {

                        //it might happen that several async queries were in progress if a user were typing fast
                        //but we are interested only in responses that correspond to the current view value
                        var onCurrentRequest = (inputValue === modelCtrl.$viewValue);
                        if (onCurrentRequest && hasFocus) {
                            if (matches && matches.length > 0) {

                                scope.activeIdx = focusFirst ? 0 : -1;
                                scope.matches.length = 0;

                                //transform labels
                                for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                                    locals[parserResult.itemName] = matches[i];
                                    scope.matches.push({
                                        id: getMatchId(i),
                                        label: parserResult.viewMapper(scope, locals),
                                        model: matches[i]
                                    });
                                }

                                scope.query = inputValue;
                                //position pop-up with matches - we need to re-calculate its position each time we are opening a window
                                //with matches as a pop-up might be absolute-positioned and position of an input might have changed on a page
                                //due to other elements being rendered
                                scope.position = appendToBody ? $position.offset(element) : $position.position(element);
                                scope.position.top = scope.position.top + element.prop('offsetHeight');

                                element.attr('aria-expanded', true);
                            } else {
                                resetMatches();
                            }
                        }
                        if (onCurrentRequest) {
                            isLoadingSetter(originalScope, false);
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        resetMatches();
                        isLoadingSetter(originalScope, false);
                    });
                };

                resetMatches();

                //we need to propagate user's query so we can highlight matches
                scope.query = undefined;

                //Declare the timeout promise var outside the function scope so that stacked calls can be cancelled later
                var timeoutPromise;

                var scheduleSearchWithTimeout = function (inputValue) {
                    timeoutPromise = $timeout(function () {
                        getMatchesAsync(inputValue);
                    }, waitTime);
                };

                var cancelPreviousTimeout = function () {
                    if (timeoutPromise) {
                        $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
                    }
                };

                //plug into $parsers pipeline to open a customTypeahead on view changes initiated from DOM
                //$parsers kick-in on all the changes coming from the view as well as manually triggered by $setViewValue
                modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                    inputValue = getLastWord(inputValue);
                    hasFocus = true;

                    if (minLength === 0 || inputValue && inputValue.length >= minLength) {
                        if (waitTime > 0) {
                            cancelPreviousTimeout();
                            scheduleSearchWithTimeout(inputValue);
                        } else {
                            getMatchesAsync(inputValue);
                        }
                    } else {
                        isLoadingSetter(originalScope, false);
                        cancelPreviousTimeout();
                        resetMatches();
                    }

                    if (isEditable) {
                        return inputValue;
                    } else {
                        if (!inputValue) {
                            // Reset in case user had typed something previously.
                            modelCtrl.$setValidity('editable', true);
                            return inputValue;
                        } else {
                            modelCtrl.$setValidity('editable', false);
                            return undefined;
                        }
                    }
                });

                modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {

                    var candidateViewValue, emptyViewValue;
                    var locals = {};

                    // The validity may be set to false via $parsers (see above) if
                    // the model is restricted to selected values. If the model
                    // is set manually it is considered to be valid.
                    if (!isEditable) {
                        modelCtrl.$setValidity('editable', true);
                    }

                    if (inputFormatter) {

                        locals.$model = modelValue;
                        return inputFormatter(originalScope, locals);

                    } else {

                        //it might happen that we don't have enough info to properly render input value
                        //we need to check for this situation and simply return model value if we can't apply custom formatting
                        locals[parserResult.itemName] = modelValue;
                        candidateViewValue = parserResult.viewMapper(originalScope, locals);
                        locals[parserResult.itemName] = undefined;
                        emptyViewValue = parserResult.viewMapper(originalScope, locals);

                        return candidateViewValue !== emptyViewValue ? candidateViewValue : modelValue;
                    }
                });

                scope.select = function (activeIdx) {
                    //called from within the $digest() cycle
                    var locals = {};
                    var model, item;

                    locals[parserResult.itemName] = item = scope.matches[activeIdx].model;
                    model = parserResult.modelMapper(originalScope, locals);
                    $setModelValue(originalScope, model);
                    modelCtrl.$setValidity('editable', true);
                    modelCtrl.$setValidity('parse', true);

                    onSelectCallback(originalScope, {
                        $item: item,
                        $model: model,
                        $label: parserResult.viewMapper(originalScope, locals)
                    });

                    resetMatches();

                    //return focus to the input element if a match was selected via a mouse click event
                    // use timeout to avoid $rootScope:inprog error
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    }, 0, false);
                };

                //bind keyboard events: arrows up(38) / down(40), enter(13) and tab(9), esc(27)
                element.bind('keydown', function (evt) {

                    //customTypeahead is open and an "interesting" key was pressed
                    if (scope.matches.length === 0 || HOT_KEYS.indexOf(evt.which) === -1) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // if there's nothing selected (i.e. focusFirst) and enter is hit, don't do anything
                    if (scope.activeIdx == -1 && (evt.which === 13 || evt.which === 9)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    evt.preventDefault();

                    if (evt.which === 40) {
                        scope.activeIdx = (scope.activeIdx + 1) % scope.matches.length;
                        scope.$digest();

                    } else if (evt.which === 38) {
                        scope.activeIdx = (scope.activeIdx > 0 ? scope.activeIdx : scope.matches.length) - 1;
                        scope.$digest();

                    } else if (evt.which === 13 || evt.which === 9) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.select(scope.activeIdx);
                        });

                    } else if (evt.which === 27) {
                        evt.stopPropagation();

                        resetMatches();
                        scope.$digest();
                    }
                });

                element.bind('blur', function (evt) {
                    hasFocus = false;
                });

                // Keep reference to click handler to unbind it.
                var dismissClickHandler = function (evt) {
                    if (element[0] !== evt.target) {
                        resetMatches();
                        if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
                            scope.$digest();
                        }
                    }
                };

                $document.bind('click', dismissClickHandler);

                originalScope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    $document.unbind('click', dismissClickHandler);
                    if (appendToBody) {
                        $popup.remove();
                    }
                    // Prevent jQuery cache memory leak
                    popUpEl.remove();
                });

                var $popup = $compile(popUpEl)(scope);

                if (appendToBody) {
                    $document.find('body').append($popup);
                } else {
                    element.after($popup);
                }
            }
        };

    }])

.directive('customTypeaheadPopup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            matches: '=',
            query: '=',
            active: '=',
            position: '&',
            select: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'html/templates/custom-typeahead-popup.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.templateUrl = attrs.templateUrl;

            scope.isOpen = function () {
                return scope.matches.length > 0;
            };

            scope.isActive = function (matchIdx) {
                return scope.active == matchIdx;
            };

            scope.selectActive = function (matchIdx) {
                scope.active = matchIdx;
            };

            scope.selectMatch = function (activeIdx) {
                scope.select({activeIdx: activeIdx});
            };
        }
    };
})

.directive('customTypeaheadMatch', ['$templateRequest', '$compile', '$parse', function ($templateRequest, $compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            index: '=',
            match: '=',
            query: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var tplUrl = $parse(attrs.templateUrl)(scope.$parent) || 'html/templates/custom-typeahead-match.html';
            $templateRequest(tplUrl).then(function (tplContent) {
                $compile(tplContent.trim())(scope, function (clonedElement) {
                    element.replaceWith(clonedElement);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])

.filter('customTypeaheadHighlight', function () {

    function escapeRegexp(queryToEscape) {
        return queryToEscape.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, '\\$1');
    }

    return function (matchItem, query) {
        return query ? ('' + matchItem).replace(new RegExp(escapeRegexp(query), 'gi'), '<strong>$&</strong>') : matchItem;
    };
});
```

Comment: You need to do some work to reduce your code. I hardly believe anyone would go through all of this to debug this issue for you. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)